# How can I maintain HD resolution with WebRTC on Android mobile

Tags: android, google-chrome, webrtc

I'm making WebRTC-node.js service based on [this source](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/MultiRTC).
I want to make video chat between PC(Chrome) and mobile(Android Chrome) at HD resolution(1280x720).

When I set the constraints to 1280x720, bandwidth to 2000 and tested, the video from mobile has good quality(1280x720) at first but fall to low quality after few seconds while the video from PC maintain good quality.

I read this QnA: [Why does video resolution change when streaming from Android via WebRTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742963/why-does-video-resolution-change-when-streaming-from-android-via-webrtc)

It says:

> The degradation you're seeing is in the PeerConnection layer, not in the getUserMedia layer. Degradation is triggered by the webrtc implementation when hardware and bandwidth statistics are indicative of low performance, and is negotiated by both sides.

For some bandwidth suspicions, I tested in local network too, but the result was same.
And instead node.js, I tried XSockets.WebRTC but the result was same.

So, how can I maintain HD resolution from android mobile?
Is that a Chrome-vp8 issue?

I need your help. Thank you.

Comment: What is your CPU utilization on the android device?

Comment: Oops! It's over 90%, almost 100%! CPU is Qualcomm SnapDragon 800 2.3GHz Quad-core. Is that bad to manage HD video with WebRTC?? Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: I am not sure when chrome on android started taking advantage of hardware acceleration but I know that on those devices, if you do not have hardware acceleration for VP8 or 9 it will absolutely kill performance. I know in a native application there is an option for hardware acceleration but I am not sure if it is 100% reliable(I have ran into performance issues myself).

Comment: So, maybe the best way is building native android app, isn't it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

To maintain stable video quality you have to set `enableCpuOveruseDetection` flag to `false` in `RTCConfiguration` of `PeerConnection` and make sure `VideoCapture` set desire video resolution using `startCapture` method (you can use `getSupportedFormats` of `CameraEnumerator` to get reasonable supported video resolution of phone camera).

This give you stable HD video resolution (if you set it by `startCapture`) and higher (unless bandwidth is sufficient), but downside it may increase battery consumption and may lead to cpu overheat (especially for some old Android phones).

```
 factory.createPeerConnection(PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(iceServers).apply {
        ...
        enableCpuOveruseDetection = false
    }, object : PeerConnection.Observer {
     ...
    })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixes the problem per a quick test for me. I believe this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works for android, but what should I do for IOS? RTCConfiguration has not "enableCpuOveruseDetection" field.

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC has introduced RTCDegradationPreference
ref: https://w3c.github.io/mst-content-hint/#dom-rtcrtpsendparameters-degradationpreference

With this, developers can choose how WebRTC should behave when the device's condition (bandwidth, CPU) degrades.
To use this in Android, one might do something like so:

```
RtpParameters parameters = localPeer.getSenders().get(0).getParameters();
parameters.degradationPreference = RtpParameters.DegradationPreference.MAINTAIN_RESOLUTION;
```

Make sure to use the latest version of WebRTC to have access to this API.
If, for some reasons, you are stuck with older version of WebRTC, use this alternative hack to disable CPU Overuse detection (assuming this is the reason why your resolution goes down, if it is because of bandwidth, then your only option is to reduce the FPS)

```
MediaConstraints constraints = new MediaConstraints();
constraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googCpuOveruseDetection", "false"));
localPeer.createAnswer(new SdpObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSetSuccess() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateFailure(String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSetFailure(String s) {
        }
    }, constraints);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Tried to set up the degradationPreference via `RtpParameters` right after I add track to local peer. But it seems it does not pick it up, as it's still decreasing resolution due to high CPU usage. Have you perhaps configured something else to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In WebRTC official repository https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/

The file /talk/media/base/videoadapter.cc shows that WebRTC would reduce video resolution according to device CPU load. This feature is enabled by default.

I built the native iOS app with video adapter disabled, but the 720p video is not smoothly enough in iPhone 6s.